# How can I restrict access to ALL devise controllers by IP address'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How can I restrict access to ALL devise controllers by IP address'? I am trying to allow only users from a specific IP address to view the admin interface / pages.

I found this approach. Which is to include a restrict_access method in the before filter. However, its a bit repetitive if I have to copy this method on all the Devise controllers that I currently use.

Is there a better approach?

```
class Admin::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_filter :restrict_access

  # Needed to restrict access to a set of IP's only. We don't want random users trying to access the admin interface
    def restrict_access
      if Rails.env == 'development' or Rails.env == 'test'
        whitelist = ['59.120.201.20', '59.120.201.21'].freeze
      else
        whitelist = ['59.120.201.20', '59.120.201.21'].freeze
      end

      unless whitelist.include? request.remote_ip
        redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Access denied!'
      end
    end
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a class like the following and place it in `RAILS_ROOT/lib/blacklist_constraint.rb`.

```
class BlacklistConstraint
  def initialize
    if Rails.env == 'development' or Rails.env == 'test'
      @whitelist = ['59.120.201.20', '59.120.201.21'].freeze
    else
      @whitelist = ['59.120.201.20', '59.120.201.21'].freeze
    end
  end

  def matches?(request)
    !@whitelist.include?(request.remote_ip)
  end
end
```

... and in your routes.rb file...

```
match "*", :constraints => BlacklistConstraint.new, :controller => "blacklist", :action => "my_access_denied_action"
```

You may need to load the class in an initializer, or modify your `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)` in `config/application.rb` (Rails3.x).

Answer (score 3):

I believe all of the Devise Controller extend your Application controller, so you could put the method in the ApplicationController as a protected method then you only need to call the

```
before_filter :restrict_access
```

on each devise controller.